# Integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}$

Tags: integration

I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = arcsin(x)$, but what is the the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}$? Is this how you do it?

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \arcsin\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: The $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor should disappear. Try doing a substitution of $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$, so $\color{blue}{du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple u-substitution problem. Use $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$:

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\,dx=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}}\,dx=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx=
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du=\\
\arcsin{u}+C=\arcsin{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}}dx=\int\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}}dx=\sin^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

By considering the general integral $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$ and  applying the substitution $$x=a\sin u$$

You can calculate that $$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) $$